# How to typeORM a manyToOne relation on multiple columns with a specific value

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to create a TypeORM relation between 2 tables.

Table listvalues

| ID | subId | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | city | London |
| 2 | 2 | city | Birmingham |
| 3 | 1 | country | England |
| 4 | 2 | country | Scotland |

Table addresses

| ID | country | city | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Palace |

I know how to link these relations with SQL or the QueryBuilder, but for good practice I want to link them with a typeORM schema.

So far I came up with this:

```js
@Entity('addresses')
export class AddressSchema extends SomeValue {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'bigint',
  })
  ID: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => ListValueSchema, (object) => object.subId)
  country: ListValueSchema

  @manyToOne(() => ListValueSchema, (object) => object.subId)
  City: ListValueSchema
}
```

I am missing something to also make it link on the type like below

```js
  @manyToOne(() => ListValueSchema, (object) => object.subId && object.type === 'city')
  City: ListValueSchema
```

Any help is welcome :-)